# Set "Check out and edit" as initial option when opening a File

Tags: document-library

As written in title, I'm looking for a way to set the initial option to "Check out and edit" instead of "read-only" when I open a document in document library.

Going around many sites, I can not get any idea about it.
Hope someone can help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require checkout on edit in the library itself.

Here's how:

1. Go to the library you want to apply this to.
2. Go to the Library tab -> Library Settings
3. Go to Versioning Settings
4. Require Check Out -> Click YES.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I want to do is not to force user to check out document on edit. I already configured as you say, and when I click document link in document library, a dialog will be shown with two option; "read-only" or "check-out and edit". the default is set to "read-only" but I want to set "check-out and edit" as default. Do you have any idea?